# how do I render a specific view from an an urelated action?

Tags: php, view, controller, yii

I need to render the view for controller=user action=profile from a
controller = b action =c
i.e. /b/c will render the same view as when I surf to /user/profile
How can this be achieved (except using include inside the view file) in Yii?
What code do I have to  put in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a "root view path" syntax to render any view file by starting with "//" like:

```
$this->render('//user/profile');
```

Answer (score 2):

To render which view is not decided by the controller or action id, you can modify it easily. Just change this line in your b controller c action:

```
$this->render('[path alias to your user/profile view]',array(
            $model=>[your data provider]
        ));
```

You can check the manual to find how to make a path alias, here's an example:

```
application.views.user.profile
```